# Laravel does not return data to the view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

My `Laravel-5.4` project was working fine. but now it's driving me crazy when trying to return data from controller to the view:

Requested url is :

```
Route::middleware(['web'])->group(function () {
    Route::prefix('service')->group( function () {
        Route::get('{service_slug}', 'ServiceController@findBySlug')->name('service.find_by_slug');
    });
});
```

Controller action is as below:

```
function findBySlug ($slug)
{
   return back()->withMessage('test message');
}
```

Here in the blade view i can not catch `$message` variable, in fact there is no `$message` variable in the view.

```
 @php
 if (isset($message))
   dd($message);
 @endphp
```

How can i fix it?...thanks.

Comment: try `{{ session('message') }}`

Comment: @shukshin.ivan Thank you, it works when trying to get data through `session`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are redirecting. You are 'flashing' data to the session when you redirect 'with` data like that. You have to get it from the session.

Also there is nothing related to passing something from the controller to a view in your post.

[Docs 5.4 - Responses - Redirecting with flashed session data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data)